# After reading in information from a file, an infinite loop occurs

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am reading employee information from a file, which looks like the following:

```
I
20017
Boris         
Pallares      
Board Room      
President       
550450.5
P
E
D
20017
P
E
Q
```

where P is for printing, E is for all, D is for delete, and Q is for quit. When deleting something, the number following, "D", is the ID that is searched for in the array.

I am running into an infinite loop when I try to print more than one employee or delete an existing employee. The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


ifstream input ("DATA7A.txt", ios::in);
ofstream output ("Output.txt",ios::out);

struct EmployeeType
{
int ID;
string fName;
string lName;
string dept;
string title;
float pay;
};

class EmployeeClass
{
public:
void GetInfo(ifstream &, int &);
string getfName(int num) {return Emp[num].fName;};
int getID(int num) {return Emp[num].ID;};
string getlName(int num) {return Emp[num].lName;};
string getDept(int num) {return Emp[num].dept;};
string getTitle(int num) {return Emp[num].title;};
float getPay(int num) {return Emp[num].pay;};
void PrintInfo(ofstream &, ifstream &, int &);
void Delete(ifstream &, int &);
private:
EmployeeType Emp[50];
static float TotalPayroll;
};

void Header(ofstream &);
void Footer(ofstream &);

float EmployeeClass::TotalPayroll = 0.0;

int main()
{
EmployeeClass Employee;
int EU = 0;
int IDNum = 0;
string code;
string pCode;
output.setf(ios::fixed);
output.precision(2);
Header(output);
getline(input,code); //read in first transaction code
while(code != "Q" || code!="D")
{
    if(code == "D")
    {
        Employee.Delete(input,EU);
    }
    if(code == "I")
    {
        Employee.GetInfo(input, EU);
        EU++;
    }
    else if(code == "P" || code == "p")
    {
        Employee.PrintInfo(output, input, EU);
    }
    getline(input,code); //read in next transaction code
}
Footer(output);
return 0;
}
void EmployeeClass::GetInfo(ifstream &input, int &EU)
{
input >> Emp[EU].ID;
input >> ws;
getline(input,Emp[EU].fName);
input >> ws;
getline(input,Emp[EU].lName);
input >> ws;
getline(input, Emp[EU].dept);
input >> Emp[EU].title;
input >> Emp[EU].pay;
return;
}

void EmployeeClass::PrintInfo(ofstream &output, ifstream &input, int &EU)
{
string pCode;
input >> pCode;
if(pCode == "E")
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<EU;i++)
    {
    output << setw(5) << Emp[i].ID;
    output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].fName;
    output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].lName;
    output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].dept;
    output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].title; 
    output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].pay << endl;
    }
}
else if(pCode == "S")
{
    int search;
    input >> search;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<EU;i++)
    {
        if(search == Emp[i].ID)
        {
        output << setw(5) << Emp[i].ID;
        output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].fName;
        output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].lName;
        output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].dept;
        output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].title; 
        output << setw(5) << " "<< Emp[i].pay << endl;
        }

    }
}
return;
}

void EmployeeClass::Delete(ifstream &input, int &EU)
{
int IDSearch;
int i;
input >> IDSearch;
for(i=0;i<EU;i++) 
{
    if(Emp[i].ID == IDSearch)
    {
        while(i<EU)
        {
            Emp[i].fName = Emp[i+1].fName;
            Emp[i].lName = Emp[i+1].lName;
            Emp[i].dept = Emp[i+1].dept;
            Emp[i].title = Emp[i+1].title;
            Emp[i].pay = Emp[i+1].pay;
            i++;
        }
        EU--;
    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: @LogicStuff I am not sure, but I think it's in the main function. I can read in the first employee and print it out, but anything after that doesn't work.

Comment: Please, be sure. It's your code.

Comment: That is why I am asking. Do you see any issues with the while loop in the main function?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `std::getline` doesn't clear the passed string once the extraction reaches the end of the stream, so `code` is left as it was before... but I see that's not...

**The main issue is that you don't check if there was something extracted from the input stream.**

A better way to write the loop would be:

```
// make use of the return value of std::getline, pretty idiomatic
while(getline(input,code) && (code != "Q" || code != "D")) // only one getline, remove the other calls
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the infinite loop. However, nothing is showing up in my output now... Do you have any ideas why that would be happening?

Comment: Give me a sample input.

Comment: To clarify, I can only get the first employee to print. Any employee information after that does not print.

Comment: I
    20017
    Boris         
    Pallares      
    Board Room      
President       
    550450.5
    I
87023
Alex          
Richter       
Sales           
Chief Associate 
98203.71 
P
E
Q

Comment: Each is on its own line though. "I" is for a new employee

Comment: Formatted extraction and `std::getline` don't mix too well. The code characters should be on separate lines too, are they?

Comment: Yes, "I" is on its own line, 20017 is on its own line, I just can't seem to format it correctly. 20017 is an integer, and 98203.17 is a float, which I have defined in the structure. I am reading them in as such in my Read() function.

Comment: You didn't post `Header` and `Footer`'s definitions.

Comment: I didn't include them for clarity's sake, but they are in my full code.

Comment: How should I reproduce your problem then? I also don't want to anymore.

Comment: I can either edit my post to include them, or you can just delete the function calls, seeing as they aren't pertinent to the problem. Thank you for your help so far, I do appreciate it.